Measuring resistance of conductive carbon parts
I'm trying to set up a resistance measurement of a carbon infused pad. From specification I know the resistance should be around 500 Ohm, however, when pressed against two conductive surfaces using a constant pressure (either low or high), using multimeter, I measure a higher initial resistance value around 600 Ohm that keeps falling in an exponential manner to a value around 300 Ohm.
For low resistance pads there is a good 4-point measurement method, link below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBnHPl8bQqo
This should not be needed for the case of higher resistance objects, however:
Do you think that that the resistance falls purely due to mechanical effects?
Is there a better way of measuring resistance of carbon materials that tend to deform?

Carbon particle conductance is pressure dependent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_microphone Any apparatus would need to define points of contact and force, e.g., suing a grid held with constant spring tension.

What are your conductive surfaces?  Is it possible that there's an oxide layer doing some insulating, giving you capacitive coupling to your carbon rod?

What is the tolerance on the 500 ohm value? "around 500 ohms is not a tolerance." 600 ohms could very well be within the specification.

Surface Oxidation, Carbon surface roughness smoothness, test method and carbon types.
The conductive surfaces or the pad itself may have thin layers of oxide or carbon particles that contribute to the initial resistance. These particle peaks may then flatten into the molecular gaps and thus increase the contact area with conductor carbon molecules previously not making contact. Sustained pressure or current flow can break down these layers, leading to a short-term settling time with improved conductivity. It may or may not be elastic but repeatability tests will show this.
Repeatability life tests must be performed and depend on dwell time during/between pressure contacts and atmospheric conditions for a large number of cycles. Switches are expected to last over 10k cycles and mechanical ones are much higher and the conductance will degrade.
I suggest you define a test method that models the end-use application for 3 sigma, Max, & min statistics ranges and mean shift over time with aging.  Then compute the Cpk or process capability with the UL/LL control limits.
It doesn't make sense to use a pressure different from the application unless you need to optimize the area for the intended force and obtain a minimum reliable conductor overall stress variables. This may require a multivariable test method to determine the quality of the sample and its 3-sigma result.
As carbon is semi-conductive and semi-insulative one might also include AC impedance measurements using the air gap as capacitance and resistive between the two conductive layers.  A complex measurement method may be more useful for testing and application.
i.e. Measure Z(f)= R+X(f)
There are also variations in carbon molecule makeup that affect mechanical and electrical properties. An extreme variation of carbon is C60, which is very elastic, like an insulative soccer ball that may only show up in tiny quantities depending on the method of sputtering carbon in an inert gas.

If you want the resistance of the sheet you should do a 4-point measurement. If you want the resistance of the sheet plus contact resistances you should do a 2-point measurement.
I wouldn't make any assumptions about the contact resistance.

Yes, most resistance measurements are contact dependent. Carbon is no exception. You might try different probe shapes (rounded, flat and sharp points) to see if that can help make better contact.
